# Creating a dynamic frame/ Adding a panel to a frame during runtime

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jpanel

I'm very much a rookie to java and I am trying to make a GUI client which once a button is pressed, then a new panel will be added to the frame. In this instance, when the a button called createMessage is pressed then the following panel will be added to the main frame.

```
    JPanel createMessagePanel = new JPanel();

    createMessagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 0, 5, 10));

    messageText = new JTextArea(5, 20);

    sendTo = new JTextField("Recipient"); //Declared Global

    JLabel createMessagePrompt = new JLabel("CREATE MESSAGE");
    JLabel userPrompt = new JLabel("Send to:");
    JLabel messagePrompt = new JLabel("Message:");

    sendButton = new JButton("Send!");
    createAMessageButton.addActionListener(this);

    createMessagePanel.add(createMessagePrompt);
    createMessagePanel.add(userPrompt);
    createMessagePanel.add(sendTo);
    createMessagePanel.add(messagePrompt);
    createMessagePanel.add(new JScrollPane(messageText));
    createMessagePanel.add(sendButton);

    add(createMessagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This sadly doesn't work, I've been told that this may be down to that the frame needs to know about the components added to the frame at runtime. How would I be able to achieve this effect of upon a button pressed then different panels which contains other components would be displayed in the position BorderLayout.CENTER.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are really a rookie in Java, I really don't think that making GUI is the best thing to start with.

Comment: Try `revalidate()` and `repaint()` your panel.

Comment: Put a `CardLayout` in the `CENTER`, add the new component to the center panel, then show that card.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Agree with talnicolas re. 'in too deep'.